# Login during splashscreen with Xamarin iOS/Android using MvvmCross

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

When my Xamarin app starts, I try to automatically login the user based on some stored credentials.

The login works, but during startup the splash-screen disappears for a second or two showing a black screen.

When I disable the auto-login feature, the splash-screen smoothly transfers to the next view.

Here is the code:

```
    public async void Start(object hint = null)
    {
        _secureStorageService = Mvx.Resolve<ISecureStorageService>();

        ClearParameterCacheUponStart();
        SetPushTokenRequirement();


        var loginService = Mvx.Resolve<ILoginService>();

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Debug.WriteLine("Start loginService");
        if (HasUsernameAndPassword() && await loginService.TryLoginWithStoredCredentials())
        {
            ShowViewModel<DashboardViewModel>();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>(true);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Finished loginService: {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Is this the right place to login the user? Or are there any better solutions for this Xamarin-MvvmCross project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do something similar in my app. However instead of communicating with a server, I simply store a token in persistent storage and check if it is present. I am generally against having splash screens, so what I do instead is mimic the layout I am going to show without any content in it until the app is ready. Anyways, maybe add the code you are using for your SplashScreen, how does that look?

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron, I will look in to it and let you know